# How Do I show RTF formatted text in Xamarin Forms Android

Tags: xamarin.forms

Hi all I'm trying to display a RTF formatted text file in Xamarin Forms Android. I have included the file as an EmbeddedRescource and can read it using StreamReader into a string. However I can not display this if I use a label (Text or FormatedText) all I see is the 'raw' data not a nicely formatted page. I have tried using HTML and XML file formats but this makes no difference.

Comment: Can you add that kind of sample RTF data here as reference & a snap show of the output as how its been displayed

Comment: There is no built-in RTF text viewer. Look for third-party controls.  OR Can you convert your RTF file to HTML? There is support for that.

Comment: I created a document in Word and saved it as HTML but that also did not work correctly. Can you tell me how to display formatted HTML? FYI it needs to be on a transparent background.